# Is there a way to set the default order of grid columns in a custom screen?

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom screen with a grid section, and I've dragged the columns in the Customization Project Editor grid fields section to the order that I want them.  I've unpublished all, republished, and reset grid fields to default and they still don't show up in the order I have them in in the Customization Project Editor grid section.  Nothing seems to make any difference.  Is there somewhere I can set the default order besides the customization editor?   Where would the table be that holds the field orders, as perhaps editing that would help...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Acumatica is keeping the Grid configuration for users in the `GridPreferences` table.

I recommend unpublishing the package and publishing back using the Publish with Cleanup action. If that doesn't work try to reset the configuration of the Grid with Reset To Default button. If that doesn't work too, then delete the record for that Screen for your user from the `GridPreferences` table.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, none of that seems to work.  Does the order I drag those fields in the 'Column Configurations' screen end up translating to the customization project?  I wouldn't think so, but I figured I'd ask.

Comment: @pmfith try clearing your browser's cache after resetting everything. No, it is not adding anything to the customization project.